# Exporting a MS SQL express database

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

I'm attempting to take a current website that uses MS SQL Express 2005 and create a redundant site on another domain.

I've only ever worked with MySQL, and can't seem to find a way to export this data. I think I read somewhere that I need to download some program to do it? What do I need to do to export this database and import it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a backup and then a restore. These steps can be made by t-sql or by GUI, anyway read the manual about backup and restore.

Comment: Can I connect to the remote database using a local copy of SQL Server, or using some other software, or is it all done via the control panel on the website?

Answer (score 2):

For a command line Backup of SQL Server , similar to mysqldump try this :

```
BACKUP DATABASE SampleDatabase
TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\SampleDatabase.bak' 
WITH FORMAT;
GO
```

save this in C:\backupMSSQL.SQL and then type this in command line :

```
OSQL.EXE -U sa -P -i C:\backupMSSQL.SQL
```

this should be work like mysqldump for mysql ...

Comment: nice answer.  you went and did all the work for him.   on the restore the SSMS user interface gives you a wizard to "restore from backup" and in the wizard you choose a "file source" db backup file as your restore source.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned you will need to do a backup and then a restore. To do this you will need to use SQL Server Management Studio Express which is a separate download. You can find it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en).